# Using Numpy to filter two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames. They are structured like this:

**df a**

| Letter | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |

**df b**

| Letter | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 100 |
| B | 4 | 300 |
| B | 4 | 100 |
| B | 4 | 150 |
| A | 3 | 200 |
| A | 3 | 400 |

I need to take for each combo of Letter and ID in df A values from df B and run an outlier function on then.

Currently I am using over 40,000 rows of A and a list of 4,500,000 of list b

```
a['Results'] =  a.apply(lambda x: outliers(b[(b['Letter']==x['Letter']) & (b['ID']==x['ID'])]['value'].to_list()),axis=1)
```

As you can imagine this is taking forever. Is there some mistake im making or something that can improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first aggregate every combination of `[Letter, ID]` in `df_b` into a list using `.groupby`, then merge with `df_a` and apply your `outliers` function afterwards. Should be faster:

```py
df_a["results"] = df_a.merge(
    df_b.groupby(["Letter", "ID"])["Value"].agg(list),
    left_on=["Letter", "ID"],
    right_index=True,
    how="left",
)["Value"].apply(outliers)
print(df_a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess this just makes it easier since you don't sift down 4.5M rows right?

Comment: @ShivR Exactly, going 40_000x down 4_500_000 rows takes a **lot** time.

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to merge the datasets a and b and then run a group by over letter and ID, aggregate the Value by Outlier function.

```
pd.merge(a,b,how="inner",on = ['letter','ID']).groupby(['letter','ID']).agg(outlier).reset_index()
```